# Why do JSfiddle and Chrome console return different values of the same function?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following code in `JSfiddle`.

```
var a = 1;

function five() {
    this.a = 5;
    console.log(a); //JSfiddle prints the value 1
}

five()
```

But when I paste the same exact code inside Chrome console, the function `five()` prints 5. Why?

Comment: Probably because of hoisting. In your jsFiddle, change the load type from onDomReady to <body> and see what you get

Comment: I am seeing 5 in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/6sguL84z/2/ & it is wrapped in body

Comment: @user2181397 It returns 1 on my machine. Does it have to do with whether we use different version of Google Chrome or user settings in JSfiddle itself. I paste my code there without logging in as a user and it returns 1.

Comment: @user2181397 Using a "No wrap" option as you did is exactly how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default JSFiddle wraps your code in the `window.onload` event, so you're actually running this:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var a = 1;

    function five() {
        this.a = 5;
        console.log(a); //JSfiddle prints the value 1
    }

    five()

}
```

That means that `a` is local to that function, while `this` still refers to the global object (`window`).  In the Chrome console, without the wrapper function, `var a` is creating a global variable, which are [created and stored as properties on the global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_variable), and is thus the same as `window.a` / `this.a`.

If you go to the JavaScript options and choose either of the "nowrap" options, it will log `5` in JSFiddle too:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I would write the code this way to make it work 'everywhere'

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = 1;
obj.foo = function five() {
    this.a = 5;
    window.alert(this.a);  
}

obj.foo();
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question on why it's doing that.

Comment: James Thorpe had already answered. This was intended as a way to rewrite the code in order to have the same behavior in both environments